# Mac OS X 10.6.6 Apache2 Crash

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, httpd

Trying to get Apache2 working on Mac OS X 10.6.6. I get the following crash.

```
Process:         httpd [27434]
Path:            /usr/sbin/httpd
Identifier:      httpd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-02-16 20:56:12.971 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.2.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/sbin/httpd
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <486E6C61-1197-CC7C-2197-82CE505102D7> /usr/lib/dyld
```

I have checked and have libapr but its 1.0.3.9

Does anyone know of a work around or fix for this problem?

After installing apache2 I still got the same error.

```
aran:lib aran$ sudo httpd -k
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.2.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/sbin/httpd
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

Answer (score 1):

Is libapr present?

If not, try installing it:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.2.7.dylib /usr/sbin/httpd
```

If that does not work, you might want to try this:

http://diymacserver.com/installing-apache/compiling-apache-in-64-bits-mode-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: Still no luck! :-(

I get the following: 


aran:lib aran$ sudo httpd -k
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.2.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/sbin/httpd
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap

Answer (score 0):

My work around for this error was to copy libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib to libapr-1.0.2.7.dylib

I know its not actually 1.0.2.7 and would be probably better to make a symbolic link but that had failed when ever I tried it failed.

For people needing to fix this easiest method I found was too run the following command from within the /usr/lib folder.

```
cp libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib libapr-1.0.2.7.dylib
```